# does malloc(sizeof(Class1)) allocate the same size of memory as new Class1?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

For any class, say "Class1"

Does cpp standard guarantee that

```
malloc(sizeof(Class1))
```

allocate the same size of memory as allocated by new operator?

```
new Class1
```

Comment: Hmm. Not if the constructor for `Class1` itself allocates memory.

Comment: Note that the allocation function can be overloaded, and allocate any amount it desires.

Comment: This may be a simple question, phrased in such a way that it is difficult to give a simple answer.  Has `new` been overloaded?

Comment: FWIW, what `malloc` doesn't do is give you an object that you can use when you are done.  `new` allocates and creates an object, `malloc` just returns uninitialized memory.

Comment: [new T](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) calls [operator new(sizeof(T))](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and `It is unspecified whether library versions of operator new make any calls to std::malloc or std::aligned_alloc (since C++17).`

Comment: @NathanOliver interestingly enough, the new (Generated on 2022-01-16, C++23?) standard draft states: [These functions implicitly create objects (intro.object) in the returned region of storage and return a pointer to a suitable created object.](https://eel.is/c++draft/c.malloc)

Comment: @alagner That is already in C++20, but only objects of implicit-lifetime type can be created that way and these must have trivial constructors.

Comment: @alagner That was a change that was introduced in C++20, and it is not as all encompasing as the wording there suggest.  [It only creates an object for implicit-lifetime types](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#10), which is just a subset of all type.  In general, you can not rely on `malloc` to create an object.

Comment: The implementation decides, whether additional memory is allocated, e.g. for padding, tagging, debugging purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the non-array new expression's allocation function call is neither omitted nor extended as explained below, it will call an `operator new` to allocate storage with a size argument exactly equal to `sizeof` of the object type. (But not for array new expressions.)

However, a new expression's allocation might be extended to provide storage for other new expressions as well, in which case the argument given to `operator new` will be the sum of the required storage for the new objects plus necessary padding for alignment. In the other new expressions for which the extended new expression's allocation provides storage no `operator new` will called.

Additionally, a call to an allocation function may be completely omitted if the storage can be provided in another way (e.g. on the stack).

---

How an `operator new` obtains storage is less clear. `operator new` overloads and replacements can be defined by the program and are free to obtain the storage in whatever way suits them.

The default implementation of the global `operator new` which is provided by the compiler/standard library has no requirements placed on it either in regards to how it acquires the memory. It doesn't need to use `std::malloc`, for example.

In practice, I think implementations usually simply call `std::malloc` with the same size argument to acquire the memory, at least absent additional debugging mechanisms requiring additional storage.

---

So the answer depends on what exactly you identify as the size of the allocation. If you refer to the size requested by a call to `operator new`, then there may not be a unique call for the new expression, but if there is, the size argument given to it will exactly match `sizeof(Class1)`.

If you refer to the number of calls and argument given to `std::malloc`, then the standard doesn't place any requirements on whether or not `std::malloc` calls happen and with what arguments.

If you go down even further, it is also completely up to the implementation how `std::malloc` itself obtains memory. Of course that will strongly depend on the operating system and so on.

---

Aside from this allocation, the constructor call to `Class1` may also cause more memory allocations to occur (but not for the storage of the object created by `new` itself), which can never happen with `malloc`.

---

In addition to everything mentioned above, under the as-if rule, a compiler is furthermore allowed to compile the program in any way as long as it has the same observable behavior as by the rules of the abstract machine (for which the explanation above applies). Allocation in general and calls to `operator new` without observable side-effect or calls to `std::malloc` specifically are not an observable behavior and therefore in the compiled executable their number of calls and arguments with which they are called may differ. In particular calls to these functions may be optimized away by the compiler completely if they are not required. (E.g. if memory is allocated that is never used.)

Comment: Re: "The non-array new expression calls an operator new to allocate storage with a size argument exactly equal to sizeof of the object type" -- no, there is no such requirement. Further, it's not even required to call `operator new`: "An implementation is allowed to omit a call to a replaceable global allocation function (21.6.2.1, 21.6.2.2). When it does so, the storage is instead provided by the implementation or provided by extending the allocation of another new-expression." [expr.new]/10.

Comment: @PeteBecker I have added the cases of extended allocation and elided allocation. My point was that [\[expr.new\]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.new#15) upper-bounds the size argument to the "required" size, if the call happens without either of these situations.

Comment: My comment was too harsh. The rules are more subtle than I remembered.